# Does cobertura maven plugin don't work with java8 Default Method declaration in interfaces?

Tags: java, maven, java-8, maven-cobertura-plugin

I've declared my interface with java8 defult method declaration:

```
public interface MyInterface {

    default String myMethod(String str) {
        //IMPLEMENTATION
    }
}
```

Next, i executed maven goal:

```
mvn cobertura:cobertura
```

The log shows error because cobertura does not support java8 default method declaration:

```
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:cobertura (default-cli) < [cobertura]test @ extractor <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:cobertura (default-cli) @ extractor ---
[INFO] Cobertura 2.1.1 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
[INFO] Cobertura: Loaded information on 134 classes.
[WARN] JavaNCSS got an error while parsing the java file <PATH_TO_MY_INTERFACE>\MyInterface.java
ParseException in STDIN
Last useful checkpoint: "path.to.my.class.MyInterface"
Encountered " "default" "default "" at line 10, column 9.
Was expecting one of:
    "abstract" ...
    "boolean" ...
    "byte" ...
    "char" ...
    "class" ...
    "double" ...
    "enum" ...
    "final" ...
    "float" ...
    "int" ...
    "interface" ...
    "long" ...
    "native" ...
    "private" ...
    "protected" ...
    "public" ...
    "short" ...
    "static" ...
    "strictfp" ...
    "synchronized" ...
    "transient" ...
    "void" ...
    "volatile" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    "}" ...
    ";" ...
    "@" ...
    "<" ...
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Apparently, there’s no (real) support for Java 8. The CHANGELOG claims support with 2.1.1, but there are lots of open issues and threads reporting problems…

Comment: I would recommend to use JaCoCo instead of cobertura cause instrumentation is no longer needed since Java 6....

Comment: Ok khmarbaise, i will try the JaCoCo instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed to JaCoCo maven configuration and it worked.

[JaCoCo Unit Tests + Reports](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin/)